# JavaScript/CSS - find text with a particular expression and add css to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below text stored in a variable :

```
var string = "[~Folky Bee] How are you today?";
```

What I want to do is to add a class/style for only the text inside the delimiters [~Text here] which will have a final output like the following for example :

**Folky Bee** How are you today?

So far, I've tried to do the following :

```
var str = "[~Folky Bee] How are you today";
//Returns 1 (true) if the match is found (but I am getting wrong 
//results, maybe it's a wrong RegEx)
var n = str.search(/~/i);
//Then if the match is found add a color to it, but in this case I don't have 
//an id of that element so I can select it doing a .getElementById for example. 
//It's only a plain string.
```

Comment: you probably forgot to add some relevant code like the regexp you are using

Comment: So match the brackets and text inside and do a replacement?

Comment: @epascarello that's the thing, I wasn't able to match those brackets and what's more challenging is adding css to what's inside because it's whole plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could seach for brackets with tilde and take the inner group for the replacement with the style.

```js
var string = "[~Folky Bee] How are you today?<br>[~Wham!] Fine!",
    replaced = string.replace(/\[~(.*?)\]/g, '<span class="foo">$1</span>');
    //                             ^^^        keeps value       ^^ 

console.log(replaced);
document.body.innerHTML += replaced;
```

```css
.foo { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers; however, the following is not clear for me : <span class="foo">$1</span> it seems that if I replace it with any other value it still does not change anything

Comment: what does not change? the original string? (string are immutable.) which value do you like to replace?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, after your last edit it made things clear for me!